# how to mount and set /emmc@fat as main sdcard0

Tags: android, storage, sd-card, mount

Only system storage is mounted
i want enable and set default the phone storage: /emmc@fat
but the:

```
/devices/platform/mtk-msdc.0/mmc_host   auto      vfat      defaults        voldmanaged=sdcard0:emmc@fat,noemulatedsd
```

... isn't working:

the init.mt6592.rc is:

```
on init
export LD_PRELOAD /system/lib/libxlog.so

export EXTERNAL_STORAGE /storage/emulated/legacy
export SECONDARY_STORAGE /storage/sdcard1

mkdir /mnt/shell 0700 shell shell
chmod 0750 /mnt/shell
chown shell sdcard_r /mnt/shell
mkdir /mnt/shell/emulated 0700 shell shell
mkdir /mnt/shell/emulated/0 0700 shell shell
mkdir /storage/emulated 0555 root root

mkdir /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 0700 media_rw media_rw
mkdir /storage/sdcard1 0700 root root

export EXTERNAL_STORAGE /storage/emulated/legacy
export SECONDARY_STORAGE /storage/sdcard1
export EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE /mnt/shell/emulated
export EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET /storage/emulated


# Support legacy paths
symlink /storage/emulated/legacy /sdcard
symlink /storage/emulated/legacy /mnt/sdcard
symlink /storage/emulated/legacy /storage/sdcard0
symlink /mnt/shell/emulated/0 /storage/emulated/legacy

[...]
# virtual sdcard daemon running as media_rw (1023)
service sdcard /system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -l /data/media /mnt/shell/emulated
    class late_start

service fuse_sdcard1 /system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -w 1023 -d /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 /storage/sdcard1
    class late_start
    disabled

service fuse_usbotg /system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -d /mnt/media_rw/usbotg /storage/usbotg
    class late_start
    disabled
```

the fstab.mt6592 of custom rom is:

```
# Android fstab file.
#<src>           <mnt_point>         <type>    <mnt_flags and options>                 <fs_mgr_flags>
# The filesystem that contains the filesystem checker binary (typically /system) cannot
# specify MF_CHECK, and must come before any filesystems that do specify MF_CHECK
/emmc@android       /system         ext4    ro,commit=1,noauto_da_alloc             wait
/emmc@usrdata       /data           ext4    noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,discard    wait,check
/emmc@cache         /cache          ext4    noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,discard    wait,check
/emmc@protect_f     /protect_f      ext4    noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,discard    wait,check
/emmc@protect_s     /protect_s      ext4    noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,discard    wait,check
/devices/platform/mtk-msdc.1/mmc_host   auto    auto    defaults        voldmanaged=sdcard1:auto
/devices/platform/mt_usb        auto    auto    defaults    voldmanaged=usbotg:auto
```

the fstab of stock rom:

```
# Android fstab file.
#<src>           <mnt_point>         <type>    <mnt_flags and options>                 <fs_mgr_flags>
# The filesystem that contains the filesystem checker binary (typically /system) cannot
# specify MF_CHECK, and must come before any filesystems that do specify MF_CHECK

/emmc@usrdata     /data               ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc    wait,check,encryptable=footer
/emmc@protect_f   /protect_f          ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc    wait,check
/emmc@protect_s   /protect_s          ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc    wait,check
/devices/platform/mtk-msdc.0/mmc_host   auto      ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc        voldmanaged=sdcard0:emmc@fat,noemulatedsd
/devices/platform/mtk-msdc.1/mmc_host   auto      vfat      defaults        voldmanaged=sdcard1:auto
/devices/platform/mt_usb auto vfat defaults voldmanaged=usbotg:auto
```

i can mount the /emmc (Phone Storage) with this stuff:

```
# Android fstab file.
#<src>           <mnt_point>         <type>    <mnt_flags and options>                 <fs_mgr_flags>
# The filesystem that contains the filesystem checker binary (typically /system) cannot
# specify MF_CHECK, and must come before any filesystems that do specify MF_CHECK
/emmc@android       /system         ext4    ro,commit=1,noauto_da_alloc             wait
/emmc@usrdata       /data           ext4    noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,discard    wait,check
/emmc@cache         /cache          ext4    noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,discard    wait,check
/emmc@protect_f     /protect_f      ext4    noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,discard    wait,check
/emmc@protect_s     /protect_s      ext4    noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,discard    wait,check
/emmc@fat   /emmc   ext4    noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,discard    wait,check
/devices/platform/mtk-msdc.1/mmc_host   auto      vfat      defaults        voldmanaged=sdcard1:auto
/devices/platform/mt_usb auto vfat defaults voldmanaged=usbotg:auto
```

in stock rom the phone storage (/emmc) is mount **/storage/sdcard0**

```
on init
    export LD_PRELOAD /system/lib/libxlog.so
    export EXTERNAL_STORAGE /storage/sdcard0
    export SECONDARY_STORAGE /storage/sdcard1

on init
    mkdir /mnt/media_rw/sdcard0 0700 media_rw media_rw
    mkdir /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 0700 media_rw media_rw
    mkdir /storage/sdcard0 0700 root root
    mkdir /storage/sdcard1 0700 root root

    export EXTERNAL_STORAGE /storage/sdcard0

    # Support legacy paths
    symlink /storage/sdcard0 /sdcard
    symlink /storage/sdcard0 /mnt/sdcard
    symlink /storage/sdcard1 /mnt/sdcard2

[...]
# virtual sdcard daemon running as media_rw (1023)

service sdcard /system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -d /data/media /storage/sdcard0
    class late_start

service fuse_sdcard0 /system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -d /mnt/media_rw/sdcard0 /storage/sdcard0
    class late_start
    disabled

service fuse_sdcard1 /system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -w 1023 -d /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 /storage/sdcard1
    class late_start
    disabled

service fuse_usbotg /system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -d /mnt/media_rw/usbotg /storage/usbotg
    class late_start
    disabled
```